# Closest parent selector in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a working code to close a custom popup using jQuery, but I want a solution using AngularJS instead of jQuery.
Anyone can help me out to find `this.closest()` in AngularJS.

I want to hide `.popOverlay` on click of `.popClose` using AngularJS, not jQuery. And I don't want to use perticular class/id becoz I have many popups like this, I want to a common solution for all of them.

Here is my working jQuery Code:

```js
function popClose(e)
{
 $(e).closest('.popOverlay').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

```css
.popOverlay { background:rgba(0,0,0,.5); width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:auto; position:fixed; left:0; top:0;}
.popBox { background:#fff; border-radius:5px; position:relative; width:400px; max-width:90%; padding:20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:50px;}
.popClose { display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:5px; right:10px; cursor:pointer; color:#f00; font:bold 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.heading { color:#0077c8; font:bold 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popOverlay">
 <div class="popBox">
  <a class="popClose" onClick="popClose(this)">x</a>
  <h3 class="blue-heading">This is a custom popup.</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want Angular solution: `ngIf`.

Comment: Yes, I want to hide `.popOverlay` on click of `.popClose` using AngularJS, not jQuery. And also consider I don't want to use perticular class/id becoz I have many popups like it, I want to common solution for all of them.

Answer (score 5):

To  achieve expected result, use ng-hide on div with class-popOverlay and set it to true on click of x

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="popOverlay" ng-hide="closePop">
    <div class="popBox">
      <a class="popClose" ng-click="popClose()">x</a>
      <h3 class="blue-heading">This is a custom popup</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.popClose= function(){
    $scope.closePop= true;
    };
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKgEbE

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popOverlay" ng-hide="popclose">
    <div class="popBox">
        <a class="popClose" onClick="popClose("true")">x</a>
        <h3 class="blue-heading">This is a custom popup.</h3>
    </div>
</div>


function popClose(status)
{
    if(status=="true"){
$scope.popclose=true;
}
}
```

try this. it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

you can use "bootstrap modal" instead.

visit http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: He's asking for an AngularJS solution.